# increment row with multiple joined tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to update the tblForm10Objectives, set the ObjectiveNumber column to an incremented number starting with 1 based on the number of rows returned from the join of tblForm10Goals, tblForm10GoalsObjectives and tblForm10Objectives where ID_Agency = an agency id that is in tblForm10Goals,

Example Query so far:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblForm10Objectives
SET ObjectiveNumber = rn
FROM tblForm10Goals As g
    Left Join tblForm10GoalsObjectives gobs ON g.ID_Form10Goal = gobs.ID_Form10Goal
    Right Join 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.ID_Agency
                            ORDER BY OB.ID_Form10Objective) AS rn,
        OB.ID_Form10Objective

    FROM tblForm10Goals g
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblForm10GoalsObjectives gobs ON g.ID_Form10Goal = gobs.ID_Form10Goal
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblForm10Objectives OB ON gobs.ID_Form10Objective = OB.ID_Form10Objective
    Where g.ID_Agency = 2
) rns ON dbo.tblForm10Objectives.ID_Form10Object = rns.ID_Form10Objective
```

The inner select statement returns the correctly incremented ObjectiveNumber values, I just need to update dbo.tblForm10Objectives with ObjectiveNumber = rn.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Scripted Tables**

**First Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblForm10Goals](
    [ID_Form10Goal] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_Agency] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GoalNumber] [int] NULL,
    [GoalDescription] [varchar](1200) NULL,
    [Locked] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblForm10Goals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Form10Goal] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Second Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblForm10GoalsObjectives](
    [ID_Form10GoalObjective] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_Form10Goal] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_Form10Objective] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblForm10GoalsObjectives] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Form10GoalObjective] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Third Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblForm10Objectives](
    [ID_Form10Objective] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectiveNumber] [int] NULL,
    [ObjectiveDescription] [varchar](1200) NULL,
    [UnitofMeasure] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Q1Target] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q1Actual] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q1ActualLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [Q2Target] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q2Actual] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q2ActualLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [Q3Target] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q3Actual] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q3ActualLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [Q4Target] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q4Actual] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q4ActualLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [AnnualTarget] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AnnualActual] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AnnualActualLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [TargetsLocked] [bit] NULL,
    [Locked] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblForm10Objectives] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Form10Objective] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Based on the format of your window function, it looks like you're using MS SQL.  If so, please tag your question as such so we know how to help you.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: the "*format*" of the window function will work on most modern DBMS. It's the presence of the `tbl` prefix and the `dbo` schema that hint at MS SQL.

Comment: I changed it to sql-server-2008, sorry about that....

Answer (score 0):

Three things leap to mind.

1. The first join to tblForm10GoalsObjectives appears to be unused, and based on the name I'd guess it's creating duplicate records.  If the relationship between the first two tables is not one-to-one, it'll break the `UPDATE`.
2. The `RIGHT JOIN` should probably be an `INNER JOIN`.  A semi-join which excluded the first table couldn't apply any update.
3. What's your error message?  Or are you just not getting the results you expect?  More detail, please.

---

Here's an attempted rewrite:

```
UPDATE Objs
SET ObjectiveNumber = RowNumbers.RowNumber
FROM tblForm10Objectives AS Objs
    INNER JOIN tblForm10GoalsObjectives AS GObjs ON Objs.ID_Form10Objective = GObjs.ID_Form10Objective
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            Objs.ID_Form10Objective,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.ID_Agency ORDER BY Objs.ID_Form10Objective) AS RowNumber
        FROM
            dbo.tblForm10Objectives AS Objs
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblForm10GoalsObjectives AS GObjs ON Objs.ID_Form10Objective = GObjs.ID_Form10Objective
            INNER JOIN tblForm10Goals AS G ON GObjs.ID_Form10Goal = G.ID_Form10Goal
        WHERE
            G.ID_Agency = 2
        ) AS RowNumbers ON GObjs.ID_Form10Objective = RowNumbers.ID_Form10Objective
```

Comment: The error message is:  The multi-part identifier "dbo.Form10Objectives.ID_Form10Objective" could not be bound.  This is showing up on the last line; rns ON dbo.tblForm10Objectives.ID_Form10Object = rns.ID_Form10Objective  The inner select works great it pulls the correct data with the ObjectiveNumbers as I would like for them to update in the update statement.  I can not get the update to work with the inner select...

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  You're throwing me off by assigning aliases and then joining using the raw table name, and by not putting the updated table first.  I've drafted an alternative, but without knowing more about the relations between your tables, it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Is there a way I can email you directly?  Your inner select works as well.  But the problem is still in the update statement, where the SET ObjectiveNumber is called, it is stating that ObjectiveNumber is invalid.  And at the bottom the statement; AS RowNumbers ON GOBS.ID_Form10Objective = RowNumbers.ID_Form10Objective, GOBS.ID_Form10Objective is an invalid column.  I would post the table structure, but this will not let me post an image being that my reputation points do not equal 10 or higher.

Comment: I'd prefer to hash it out here in SO.  Please don't post an image, a much better option is the `CREATE TABLE` script (pared down to just the fields, PKs, and UKs, please, no need for the `SET ANSI_NULLS` boilerplate).  Also, if you can explain the relationships between the tables, that would help.

Comment: I posted the scripted tables under my original post.  The scripted tables are located under the heading **Scripted Tables**.  First table has a primary key of ID_Form10Goal. The second table has a primary key of ID_Form10GoalObjective and the following Foreign Keys; ID_Form10Goal, ID_Form10Objective.  tblForm10Objectives has a primary key of ID_Form10Objective.

Comment: I've taken another stab at it.  What you're asking is a little complicated.  If this does not work for you, I recommend you break it down into steps: use some temp tables to calculate individual steps, verifying each one, until you're ready to do a single simple `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic format of an UPDATE with a JOIN:

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
    A.field = B.field
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE --Additional limiting criteria if needed.
```

Given that, and assuming your joins work properly, I believe the following should work:

```
UPDATE
    OB
SET
    ObjectiveNumber =   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.ID_Agency
                        ORDER BY OB.ID_Form10Objective)
FROM tblForm10Goals g
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblForm10GoalsObjectives gobs ON g.ID_Form10Goal = gobs.ID_Form10Goal
RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblForm10Objectives OB ON gobs.ID_Form10Objective = OB.ID_Form10Objective
Where g.ID_Agency = 2
```

Comment: When I run the query you gave above, I get the following error:  Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: So move the Row_Number creation script into a subquery and only JOIN the updated table to it.